# I want to perform some actions when I click on image in Openframeworks(C++). How to do this?

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I want to perform some actions when I click on image in Openframeworks(C++). How to do this?

I am using ***ofImage***. Help me to resolve this.

Comment: Hard to answer a question about how to perform certain actions when the actions to be performed have not been specified. But adding the actions will likely not be enough. It is best if you make an attempt at accomplishing your goals and then return with specific questions about problems you encounter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the image in `draw()` you might use a position (`x,y`) and size (`width,height`) to display on screen.

You can use the same position and dimensions values in the [mouseReleased()](http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/application/ofBaseApp/#!show_mouseReleased) event to check if the mouse coordinates (`x,y`) are within the rendered image's bounding box.

Here's a a bit of code to illustrate this, assuming you are already have the rendered image's x,y,width,height variables declared and updated:

```
void ofApp::mouseReleased(int x, int y, int button){
   if((x >= imageX && x <= imageX + imageWidth) &&
      (y >= imageY && y <= imageY + imageHeight)){
      std::cout << "image clicked" << std::endl;
   }

}
```